# How to get all privileges back to the root user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, privileges

I am using MySQL. My root user doesn't have all privileges. How can I get all privileges back to the root user? How to do it step by step?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me on Ubuntu:

Stop MySQL server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start MySQL from the commandline:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

In another terminal enter mysql and issue:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;
```

You may also want to add

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

and optionally use a password as well.

```
flush privileges;
```

and then exit your MySQL prompt and then kill the mysqld server running in the foreground.  Restart with

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me after 3 hours of googling and trying almost everything !!

Comment: `ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`

Answer (score 10):

If you facing grant permission access denied problem, you can try mysql_upgrade to fix the problem:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Login as root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Run this commands:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: `ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT` / Centos8, Mysql8

Answer (score 2):

Log in as root, then run the following MySQL commands:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Error

SQL query:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You were logged in to mysql as root when you ran this, correct?

Comment: I wonder if you need to set the password as well, and maybe the ability to grant:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password' GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Yes, I was logged in to mysql as root when I ran it. I still have my password. When I run,GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password' GRANT OPTION; it says I have an error in my SQL syntax.

Comment: It said i had an error when i did this via MYSQL Workbench but it did the command successfully if you look it may show the error being with a ( on line 1, which is not in the sql query anyway

Comment: Instead of 'GRANT OPTION' USE 'WITH GRANT OPTION'. For example : GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password' **WITH GRANT OPTION**

Comment: `ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT` / Centos8, Mysql8

Answer (score 0):

If you facing grant permission access denied problem, you can try mysql to fix the problem:

grant all privileges on *.* to root@'localhost' identified by 'Your password';

grant all privileges on *.* to root@'IP ADDRESS' identified by 'Your password?';

your can try this on any mysql user, its working.

Use below command to login mysql with iP address.

mysql -h 10.0.0.23 -u root -p