# cannot connect to local mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, localhost

I am logged into mysql with terminal on mac Lion, but I get an error running php testscript

### these where my steps:

virtualhost is "test.dev"

after Homebrew install logged in with:

```
mysql -u root
```

created database

```
CREATE DATABASE `lara` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

output php testscript

```
<?php
$num_entries = 20;
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "redres"; (at first was set to root)
$dbname = "lara";

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);


Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Users/redres/Webdev/testsite/index.php on line 19
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

now setting a password

```
mysqladmin -u root password xxx
```

**I have restarted mysql and also granted "root" al priviliges**

I still cannot connect

Where do I look to fix this?

Comment: have you tried to restart the mysql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### > mysql -u root -p

after I hit "Enter" when it asks for the password it was obvious

I thought I set a password, but that did not stick

so I try'd it another way

```
use mysql;
UPDATE user set Password=PASSWORD("NEW_PASSWORD_HERE") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

that, finally worked

( be carefull about the syntax, on some other posts the uppercasings where missing)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Log in as root, then run the following MySQL commands:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708826/how-to-get-all-privileges-back-to-the-root-user-in-mysql#answer-1708840).