# GRANT access to ROOT

Tags: mysql

I was using phpmyadmin to adjust the privileges of the users.

I removed all access for user 'root'. Now I am unable to see the tables.

I tried signing in under another user but its not allowing me.

What options do I have at this point?

Step 1.

```
//Stop mysql server

    zend
    opt 6 zendDBi
    opt 7 Stop ZendDBi
```

Step 2.

```
//Start mysql server

    cd /usr/local/mysql/bin  

    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables  
    mysql FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After I do this I get this long bit of text:

```
 /usr/local/mysql-5.1.59-i5os-power-64bit/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.59, for ibm-i5os (power) using readline 5.1
 Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.                                         

  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its                                                    
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective                                                        
  owners.                                                                                                              

   Usage: /usr/local/mysql-5.1.59-i5os-power-64bit/bin/mysql [OPTIONS]     [database]                                       
    -?, --help          Display this help and exit.          
    .............
```

After the flush I try to reconnect with mysql server I get this error:

```
 mysql -u root                                                                                   
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708826/how-to-get-all-privileges-back-to-the-root-user-in-mysql

Comment: You cannot see tables, but if you are able to login as 'root' then you can GRANT privileges in the same way you REVOKE.

Comment: mysql>                                                                                
 grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;                          
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Viswanath Polaki that did not solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password

Comment: No, Im not trying to reset the password. Thank you though

Comment: If you lost a password, accidentally removed privileges, or completely deleted the root account, you still need to follow the same set of steps. You're right that the question sounds a bit different, but at the fundamental level both the linked question and yours deal with replacing lost privileges; so you're right that it's a different question and therefore not a duplicate and I'm (mostly likely) right that the solution is the same. Anyway, in the mean time jdog has added some steps and rather than start a whole new answer of my own, I'll just try to help out there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to both start mysql with --skip-grant-tables and assign a password to root, in your case you seem to want the empty password:

1.

```
//Stop mysql server

zend
opt 6 zendDBi
opt 7 Stop ZendDBi
```

2.

```
//Start mysql server

cd /usr/local/mysql/bin  

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3.

```
grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%' with grant option identified by password('');
flush privileges;
```

4.

```
exit
```

5.

```
mysql -uroot
```

Comment: mysql grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%' with grant option identified by password(''); 
 qsh: 001-0050 Syntax error on line 6: token "(" not expected. 
 ------------- 
 mysql grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%' with grant option; 
 /usr/local/mysql-5.1.59-i5os-power-64bit/bin/mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.59, for ibm-i5os (power) using readline 5.1 
 Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. 
 ----------------------
Mysql  -u root 
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Try PASSWORD('') and make sure to use single tick

Comment: grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%' with grant option identified by PASSWORD('');   
       
 qsh: 001-0050 Syntax error on line 3: token "(" not expected.

Comment: try: use mysql;
grant all privileges on yourdatabase to 'root'@'%' identified by PASSWORD('') ; grant all privileges on yourdatabase to 'root'@'%' with grant option;

Comment: No connection. Trying to reconnect...  
 Connection id:  4  
 Current database: *** NONE *** 
  
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'  
 ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected 
 ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: Ca you check if your stopping of mysql actually works with task manager

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: I suspect it's not stopped, so you are

Comment: Connecting to the original instance.  After stopping, check in task manager that mysql is not running

Comment: mysql doesnt show up in my task manager, but I can check if the port is 'listening'. The server is shutting down.

Comment: 'root'@'%' is for TCP connections; according to the error message you're connecting via socket which means you need to use the host 'localhost' instead of the wildcard '%'