# what is error when connecting database with localhost and i can connect database with host as my local IP address?

Tags: php, mysqli

My php page and mysql server are in same server. 
I can connect database using local IP , it works.
but, when trying to connect with localhost it show the following error

**Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'**

changed mysqld.cnf file
as BIND ADDRESS = 0.0.0.0

I gave the following permission
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@my local IP IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

I don't know what is problem in my code and configuration ...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database="db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: "  . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
echo 'connected successfully';die;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708826/how-to-get-all-privileges-back-to-the-root-user-in-mysql

Comment: @NivApo  when i give **/usr/sbin/mysqld** this command no respose I get, and when using this command **grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option** the error no grand command appears

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried servername 127.0.0.1?

From the mysql manual:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server.[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html)